# Instance of a Java class is not getting null on application close in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I have a class defined as

```
public class ApiManager
{
    private static ApiManager mInstance;
    public static synchronized ApiManager getInstance()
    {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public ApiManager(Context mContext)
    {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        mInstance = this;
    }
}
```

My SplashActivity is defined as

```
public class SplashActivity extends BaseActivity
{
    private String gcmRegId;
    private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancelAll();

        try {
            if(ApiManager.getInstance() != null)
            {
                /* Activity already present. We need to move to main activity */
                finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
        }
```

My MainActivity onDestroy is defined as

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(isFullScreen)
        {
            animateFullScreenClose();
            if (mainMapFragment.postLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                mainMapFragment.closePinDetails();
        }
        else
        {
            MyApplication.getInstance().disconnectGoogleApi();
            SocketManager.getInstance().closeConnection();
            finish();
            MyApplication.getInstance().stopService();
        }
    }
}
```

When i press the back button. Everything should get stop. Application closes.

However when i open the application again using launcher icon on android Main Menu, `if(ApiManager.getInstance() != null)` fails to consider as null and instead of Splash i ended up on mainActivity,

why is `ApiManager.getInstance()` not null if application is closed.

Comment: When you press back button, your app enters onPause(), it doesn't stop yet.

Comment: Because you never set it to null?

Comment: @immibis my question is, when app closes, why they do not get null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static object are per process. U close your activity but u didnt close the process therefore there is still value in *ApiManager.getInstance* in order to clear the value and return to the splash screen again, just clear the object manually at *onDestroy* of your *MainActivity*

> onDestroy(){
>   ApiManager.clear();
>   }
>
> public static void clear(){ if (mInstance != null){ mInstance = null;
>   }

Comment: if i try to do something like ApiManager.getInstance.setInstance(null) , mInstance = null, it crashes , as null pointer, i am doing this after finish